# How to get the wifi card intel 7260M work on Jetson TK1?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, network-interface, intel, iwlwifi

I reflash the jetson tk1 to 21.6.Below shows that I succeeded:

```
head -n 1 /etc/nv_tegra_release
# R21 (release), REVISION: 6.0, GCID: 9887687, BOARD: ardbeg, EABI: hard, DATE: Sat Oct 14 01:25:24 UTC 2017
```

And after this I run installGrinch.sh which was cloned form git repo.Below shows I also succeeded in this :

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux tegra-ubuntu 3.10.40-grinch-21.3.4 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 1 10:41:09 UTC 2015 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

But after reboot， there still isn't the wifi:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0e12 (rev a1)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev cb)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0e13 (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)


ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ lspci -vvv -s 01:00.0
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev cb)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 4c70
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 130
    Region 0: Memory at 32200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

"ifconfig" :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:4b:70:94:12  
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::204:4bff:fe70:9412/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:492 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:396 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:44073 (44.0 KB)  TX bytes:47290 (47.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:696 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:696 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:55276 (55.2 KB)  TX bytes:55276 (55.2 KB)
```

And also, using command `dmesg | grep iwl` still showsed nothing at all.I Baidu/Google the reason, and tried every method I can find. Installing linux-firmware didn't work, so I installed firmware-iwlwifi from https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-iwlwifi. "dpkg -l | grep iwl" shows firmware-iwlwifi successfully installed. But the all things never fixed the problem. At last I use commad "lspci -vvv -s 03:00.0" to show details of the ethernet controller.The output was below:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ lspci -vvv -s 03:00.0
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 0123
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 642
    Region 0: I/O ports at 10000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at 32100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 4: Memory at 12100000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

At the last line there is "**Kernel driver in use: r8169**", but above infomation of "lspci -vvv -s 01:00.0" didn't have this. So what's wrong actually? the driver or the kernel?

Comment: The Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 work only on a  Kernel version > 4.1 . I don't know if it is possible to upgrade to Xenial or Debian Stretch or not. If it is possible you can solve this problem. The `r8169` is the ethernet driver . The wirless driver should be `iwlwifi`.

Comment: Sir, I am new to Ubuntu and Jetson TK1.Yesterday I reflash the tk1 board.The output of `uname -r` is :`Linux tegra-ubuntu 3.10.40-gb271e8f #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 13 18:07:53 PDT 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
`<br> Is this kernel OK? Or how can I know the kernel version I am using?